# Chrome Extension: extension sandbox page - how to communicate with the background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I use sandbox pages in my extension to render a Vue.js app to have a less strict CSP rules than a non-sandboxed extension pages.

All works great except I can't find way how to communicate with the background service worker. `chrome` APIs are not available in the sandbox context so I can't use them directly the same way I use it in the content scripts.
I also tried injecting a content script with `message` event listener to all pages and communicate with the background script via it (using `postMessage` on the page side and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` on the content script side), but the content script is injected everywhere except my sandboxed extension page.

**manifest.ts**

```js
const manifest = (): chrome.runtime.Manifest => ({
  ...
  manifest_version: 3,
  ...
  background: {
    service_worker: 'src/background/background.js',
    type: 'module',
  },
  ...
  ...
  sandbox: {
    pages: ['web/index.html'],
  },
  content_scripts: [
    // injected everywhere, but not to the sandboxed page ^^^
    {
      matches: ['<all_urls>'],
      js: ['src/content-scripts/inject.js'],
      run_at: 'document_start',
    }
  ],
});

export default manifest;
```

`chrome.runtime` API is not available in the sandbox page context
[image: undefined chrome runtime]

Comment: It depends on how you create the sandboxed page. Note that Vue doesn't require relaxing the CSP.

Comment: @wOxxOm I open the page manually by typing the path in the Chrome url bar.

The CSP btw is coming from vue-i18n, https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/543, I might be able to fix it.

Comment: Then your only options are 1) [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) and 2) maybe `navigator.serviceWorker` messaging in case it's actually working in a sandboxed environment.